# Points based partial ranking

Tags: co.combinatorics, st.statistics, game-theory, applications, social-choice

I want to rank a population $P=\{P_1,\ldots,P_n\}$. I am given a set  $R=\{R_1,\ldots,R_k\}$ of partial rankings. The partial rankings may have varying sizes (e.g. the first ranking ranks only 8 individuals, the next ranking ranks 20 individuals, ...).

I want to assign points to each combination of individual $P_i$ and ranking $R_i$. If $P_i$ does not participate in $R_i$, $P_i$ should get 0 points. If $P_i$ participates in $R_i$, $P_i$ should get points depending on their rank in $R_i$ and the size of $R_i$.

The total points of an an individual $P_i$ is the sum of their points in their 4 best rankings.

How should I design the function that assigns points for a certain rank $j$ in a ranking of size $s$?

Comment: This question is not mathematical. You may want to try https://stats.stackexchange.com/ instead.

Comment: One case that is commonly studied, similar to your description but not exactly the same, is when we have a round-robin tournament where every player competes head-to-head against every other player. (So this would be like all your partial rankings $R$ have size $2$.) Even in this case it is quite nontrivial to assign scores to the players. One interesting approach is the "Kendall-Wei" method, where we encode the tournament as a matrix and use a principal eigenvector of this matrix to assign the scores to each player.

Comment: @IosifPinelis While some parts of the question seem a little ad hoc (like "the total points of an an individual $P_i$ is the sum of their points in their 4 best rankings"), I think the basic underlying question here is an interesting applied math question. MO often seems too hostile to any question where "how can a model this real world phenomenon" is a part of the question, but I think that these kind of questions can be okay from the point of view of applied math.

Comment: @SamHopkins : I am glad that you are able to discern some mathematics here. I still cannot. I cannot even parse some of the sentences in the post.

Comment: @IosifPinelis Can you point out which sentences you cannot understand or provide some hints how to write better posts? This is my first question, so I am sure it it not perfect.

Assuming, that the rankings are consistent (a is always better than b), we can add a metric measuring how good the total ranking is (e.g. MAE). I think we now have an optimization problem, to optimize the points assigning function to yield in expection a low MAE. This is the reason I think, the problem is mathematical.

Comment: @Max The assumption that the rankings are consistent is a big assumption. If you want to assume that, you should say so explicitly. In the tournaments business I discussed, the fact that the rankings are not always consistent (there can be upsets in a tournament) is a big source of the struggle to come up with a good raking method.

Comment: @Max : In almost every your sentence, I have to guess the intended meaning. Say, in the second sentence "I am given a set of partial rankings $R$.", is $R$ a partial ranking or is it a set of partial rankings? And why is the symbol $R$ not used anywhere else in your post? And what is a partial ranking? Etc., etc. You should try to state your question completely formally, with all terms rigorously defined -- or post it elsewhere.

Comment: @IosifPinelis : As I wrote in my answer below, this is a question in the area of Social Choice, and it is mathematical. It is true that the question is not well phrased, but I think this is why the author posted this question - because he needs references to learn how to properly phrase it.

Comment: @Eilon : I think, if a question is stated mathematically, then all the terms used there must be defined rigorously or commonly known by the audience to which the question is addressed. I do not think that this is a case here, even though I can imagine that there is a way to interpret the question mathematically, as you seem to have done. In my case, I had to be guessing the intended meaning of almost every sentence in the post, which, I think, made the probability of my correct understanding of the question close to zero.

Comment: I think we should be slow to confidently dismiss questions outside our areas of familiarity, even when there are clear problems with the question.

Comment: Anyway, there is the voting button.

Comment: The question is well written and mathematically sound. Too much choice is left undetermined however regarding how you would prefer any solution to any others -- its properties as suggested by Eilon's answer.

Comment: My (uneducated) opinion is that the suggested scheme is flawed from the beginning and cannot be salvaged by any tune-up. Imagine that we have 20 people with very different abilities (or whatever is being ranked) about which *everybody* agrees. Imagine we have all possible rankings of subgroups of 4, say. Then no matter what the function is, all but the bottom 4 people will get the maximal possible score from the proposed procedure, so if the goal is to choose a few best rather than to weed out a few worst, this approach will be totally useless. With less fair grouping it gets even worse.

Answer (score 3):

The question is in the area called social choice. You can look for textbooks that write on this topic, like Chapter 22 in ["Game Theory" by Maschler, Solan, and Zamir](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1108825141).
There are many ways to define a function as you describe. For example, the top individual gets $|P|$ points, the next gets $|P|-1$ points, etc. Or the last ranked individual gets $1$ point, the one above it $2$ points, etc. To properly answer your question, one should determine the properties required from the function you look for. Once you read some literature on social choice, you will be able to better phrase your question.

Answer (score 2):

This is an interesting question. An expert in social choice would have an interesting reply. As a semi-expert I can say semi-interesting things.

As you may know, a common voting setting in social choice is to take in a set of rankings $R_1,\dots,R_m$, each a linear order on a finite set $P$, and aggregate them into a full ranking $R$. Classically each ranking is an order or permutation on P. A partial ranking would be an order on a subset of P, or more generally could e.g. be any subset of pairwise comparisons that is consistent with some ranking. The case of aggregating partial rankings into a final order has definitely been studied.

- Some voting rules are based on pairwise comparisons. Any ranking implies a pairwise comparison between each pair of items in the ranking. It is easy to extend such a rule to partial rankings because they just give a smaller set of pairwise comparisons. For example, some rules are based on the tournament graph that Sam Hopkins mentioned, where $P$ are the vertices and the edge $(u,v)$ could e.g. be weighted by the fraction of all pairwise comparisons between $u$ and $v$ that are won by $u$. A voting rule can take this graph as input and use it to pick a winner. An old reference is ["Choosing from a tournament" by Moulin.](https://conservancy.umn.edu/bitstream/handle/11299/1645/83.pdf?sequence=1)
- If you did not have partial rankings, then you would be using the [Borda count](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borda_score), which gives the top candidate in a ranking n points, the next n-1, etc., and outputs an aggregate ranking by total points. But, I haven't heard of one that uses this "best 4 rankings" idea. Normally we think of voting as wanting to aggregate lots and lots of rankings together, not throw away information about how good an alternative is!
- But you also have partial rankings. A natural approach if the order has $k$ candidates in it is to award 1 point for first, $\frac{k-2}{k-1}$ for second, $\frac{k-3}{k-2}$ for third and so on down to $0$ for last. But any such rule would "reward" trying to only compete against bad alternatives. So it seems tricky. You could also just give 0 points for last, 1 point for second-to-last, up to k points for first. This would penalize being atop a small ranking.
- All of this is without considering "best of 4", which should be easy to do computationally, but interesting to justify.

A quick search finds one paper that is very relevant: ["The original Borda count and partial voting"](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00355-011-0603-9). It sounds like it discusses some of these issues.